# I have a issue with the if statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to execute a if statement which is like this

```
select IF ( quantity_wanted!=3,(select name from grocerywanted),Null) AS message from grocerywanted;
```

I want here to check the quantity_wanted column if it contains a value except 3 run the select statement

Comment: If is = 3 you want to display null? NB Your query is weird , I cannot imagine why you came up with this solution. and the subquery will cause an error because it attempts to return all rows.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you just want `select if(quantity_wanted!=3,name,null)` ??? If not, your subquery needs to select just a single row; if that isn't the current row, what is it?

Comment: Maybe you need in `select name from grocerywanted where quantity_wanted <> 3`?

Comment: *I want here to check the quantity_wanted column **if it contains a value except 3** run the select statement* Contains in what row? or you mean "if the value = 3 is present in at least one row then select nothing else select all"?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is using same table name not as sub query. I think you should use 'name' in replace of '(select name from grocerywanted)'. You will get your desired output.

```
select IF ( quantity_wanted!=3,name,Null) AS message from grocerywanted;
```

Comment: I tried this  solution I want to check if the column quantity_wanted contains other than the value 3 if yes I want all the values for name, currently it is only giving those names which is not equal to 3

Comment: If you give at least 5 test data & your desired result, it would be easier for me to understand your actual requirement.

Comment: @Basaier what does "I want all the values for name" look like?  you really need to show us some sample data and desired results for that sample data